# How to extract 3D mesh geometry at each keyframe from an animation file using python?

Tags: python, animation, mesh, armature, .fbx

I have a collection of animation files in (.fbx/.dae/.blend) format, that contains the animation of a human mesh performing various motions. Each animation file contains 100 frames.
I now want to write a python script in which for each animation file, I want to extract the 100 frames. Each frame should contain the geometry of the mesh (vertices and faces). What is the most efficient way to do so?

If I use the blender-python script for this, that is, precompute all the frames(.obj) for each animation file, then it consumes a very large amount of storage space. I want to compute the frames on-the-fly inside a for loop in python. The code should look something like this:

```
import glob
anim_paths = glob.glob('*.fbx') # alternatively *.dae or *.blend

for path in anim_paths:
    anim = load_animation(path) # load the animation file
    frames=extract_frames(anim) # extract all the 100 frames
    output=process_frames(frames) # process the 100 frames
```

The extraction of frames must happen inside this for loop. They should not be precomputed.

**Edited**:

One way of obtaining the meshes is as follows:
1) Load the animation files in blender (each animation file has 100 frames)
2) Use `bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=filepath,use_animation=True)` to save each of the 100 frames as an .obj file
3) Load all the 100 frames inside python and do the required computation

The drawback of this method is that storing each frame as a .obj file for each animation takes a large amount of storage in total. This would be a highly inefficient way of doing what I wish to do.

The efficient way would be to not store it on disk but compute it inside python where it is needed for further computation. The problem I am facing is that I do not know how to compute it (since I am new to the field of animation). I want to know that, is there a python library that loads an animation file and extracts the mesh geometry for each frame?

Comment: how do you want to store the results?

Comment: I just want to extract the mesh geometry for each frame on the fly. Just the way `bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=filepath,use_animation=True) ` saves .obj files for each frame which can be later loaded, I want to extract these meshes from a .fbx/.blend/.dae file in python. This is because saving .obj file for each frame consumes lot of memory.

Comment: I'm not an expert on performance, but I don't think you'll ever beat importing the scene and just looking at the meshes during animation. Maybe we would be able to help you, if we knew what you plan to do with this. Importing and reading multiple fbx each frame is bound to be very slow.